# What are ignored packages for?

Tags: macos, sublime-text-3, configure

I don't have any packages installed on my Sublime Text 3, yet I have this strange property in my configuration file.

```
"ignored_packages":
[
    "ActionScript",
    "Vintage"
],
```

Why is it there and can I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on this editor, but have used it.

From what I know this property is built into the editor and lists any disabled packages.